# .NET Console Application configSections

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application, configsection

I have a shared class library which is being used by an asp.net web application and a console application.

In the web.config of my web app, I have a sectionGroup within the configSections declared, and then the matching settings.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="StockLocator">
          <section name="AppSettings" type="StockLocator.ConfigSettings.AppConfig, StockLocator"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<StockLocator>
    <AppSettings>
        <Settings...... />
    </AppSettings>
</StockLocator>
```

Everything works when I am reading these settings in the web application. However, when I add this to the App.config of my console application, it is not able to read these settings. Basically whenever I am trying to read anything from the App.config file I just get an error `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

Not very helpful.

It seems as though this section is just not being read from the app.config file, which leads me to think that you cannot add the `configSections` to the app.config file? Or is there another way to debug this to get a better error message?

I am reading from the configSections using the code

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class AppConfig
    Inherits ConfigurationSection

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initialises and gets AppConfig SiteSettings
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function getConfig() As AppConfig
        Return CType(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("StockLocator/AppSettings"), AppConfig)
    End Function

    <ConfigurationProperty("Settings")> _
    Public Property Settings() As SettingsElement
        Get
            Return CType(Me("Settings"), SettingsElement)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As SettingsElement)
            Me("Settings") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Class SettingsElement
        Inherits ConfigurationElement

        <ConfigurationProperty("SqlConnName")> _
        Public Property SqlConnName() As String
            Get
                Return CType(Me("SqlConnName"), String)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me("SqlConnName") = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class

End Class
```

Stack Trace:

> at StockLocator.Model.StockLocatorService.MatchStock(StockLocator_Store store) in C:\projects\StockLocator\StockLocator\Model\StockLocator.vb:line 421

Comment: Can you post the full exception, include stack trace please?

Comment: Can you also post the code you are using to try and read from the app.config?

Comment: updated. Stack Trace is useless :P

Comment: do you have other appSettings in your App.config? If so [watch the order](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/220025e7-b70b-46ed-9e53-0a84f28a68e6)

Comment: @paolo thanks that worked! didn't think that it would have mattered. Currently there is the standard `<system.diagnostics>` section which was before it, and I just added the `<configSections>` below this. Could you add your comment as an answer so i can flag as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have other appSettings in your App.config their relative order matters. The configSections section should come before the appSettings. More on [this msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/220025e7-b70b-46ed-9e53-0a84f28a68e6)